# Script stuck during duplicating database table - Mysql - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, duplicates, copy

This is a follow up question to my [prev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038348/copy-duplicate-backup-database-tables-effectively-mysql/14038444#comment19394628_14038444) one.

I use the code below to duplicate database tables, but sometimes if the table size is large, the script hangs and the page just keeps waiting, and when I compare number of rows in both table I find something similar to this

> Original table count: 855057
> Backed up table count: 855022

So it seems like the process did not fully complete which brings up the questions, why it got stuck during executing of insertion statments?

Keep in mind that in most cases both counts actually the same, still, it hangs even though it finished duplicating.

Here's my code:

```
//duplicate tables structure 
 $query = "CREATE TABLE $this->dbName.`$newTableName` LIKE $this->dbName.`$oldTable`";
    ..
    ..
    
//duplicate tables data
  $query = "INSERT INTO $this->dbName.`$newTableName` SELECT * FROM $this->dbName.`$oldTable`";
    ..
    ..
```

ps. I run the duplicating script from my localhost to backup db located in remote server.

Comment: You might check to see if you are getting any errors in the php logs. You can also run "show full processlist" in mysql to see if it is still running the query.

Comment: What's the MySQL server version on each machine?

Comment: (On my machine -> 5.5.16) (on server it says -> 5.0.77-log )
I got it by running mysql_get_server_info()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOCK TABLES

```
// duplicate tables structure 
$query = "CREATE TABLE $this->dbName.`$newTableName` LIKE $this->dbName.`$oldTable`";

// lock source and target table
$query = "LOCK TABLES $this->dbName.`$newTableName` WRITE, $this->dbName.`$oldTable` AS source WRITE";

// duplicate tables data
$query = "INSERT INTO $this->dbName.`$newTableName` SELECT * FROM $this->dbName.`$oldTable` AS source";

// unlock
$query = "UNLOCK TABLES";
```

Comment: I get this error when i try to copy the data from source table:

(Error in query. Query:
 INSERT INTO db_name_here.`badges_userstats_temp_015303_271212` SELECT * FROM db_name_here.`badges_userstats_gw18_271212`
 Error: Table 'badges_userstats_temp_015303_271212' was not locked with LOCK TABLES)

does that mean i need to lock both tables!

Comment: just tested the code, no execution error :D
however,will try and see if duplicating process won't hang, if so, i will come back in a couple of day and select this as the right answer. Thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: one more thing, why do think locking the table is necessary before copy data?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to check if the query is still running by running show full processlist.
You will also have to keep in mind that if the tables engine is innodb an undo log is also created as in case of interruption the transaction will have to rollback.

Comment: Late comment, Thanks for the info!